# How i can run faust workers and manage them

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, faust

I want to run faust workers from my code (run from signals). And i need manage workers (pause, kill, reload).
In the future, I would like to manage workers in docker containers. That is, 3 workers in one container, 2 in another ...
Or maybe there are ways to better run and manage workers?
I've already learned how to run them in a container, one per container manualy.

I need a daemon for a large number of workers, such as supervisor

Comment: I'm not a SME on this, but could you provide some code that illustrates the question/problem?

Comment: I feel like scaling containers would be easier to manage than arbitrarily starting multiple workers in each container